# how do I call the answer of options from JSON and send the chosen option

Tags: javascript

in this task, I want to choose one of the alternatives and check if the answer is correct using Ajax which I already set with function sendAnswer(url, data), however all the choices I click on return wrong answer and it doesnt continue to the next question?!

```
"questions": [{
            "id" : 21,
            "question": "What is 2 + 8?",
            "alternatives": {
                "alt1": 2,
                "alt2": 8,
                "alt3": 10,
                "alt4": 28
            },
            "answer" : "alt3"
        },
```

```
function displayAlternatives(data) {
  let options = data.alternatives
  let button
for ( let alt in options) {
  button = document.createElement('button')
  //button.setAttribute('name', 'choice')
  // button.setAttribute('value', alt)
  button.innerText = options[alt]
  button.classList.add('btn')
  answerButtons.appendChild(button)


  button.addEventListener('click', selectAnswer)
  sendAnswer(data.nextURL, button.value)
}
}

function selectAnswer(guess) {

  let selectedbutton = guess.target
  let correct = selectedbutton.dataset.answer
  if (correct) {
    console.log('correct')
  } else {
    console.log('wrong')
  }
}
```

Comment: What does _selectedbutton.dataset.answer_ returns?

Comment: You have an extra `}` after the first function.

Comment: it returns the correct answer from JSON, beside, I just edited the code i forgot to show the for loop.